# Vitest - trying to mock an Object imported into a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, mocking, vite, vitest

Ok, so disclaimer.  Just starting React & Javascript from 30 years of typed languages (Java etc) so trying to get my head round it all.
(First time on here also so apologies for any layout issues).

I have a React project created using Vitest.  I have a basic function as follows that squashes 2 objects with override being the 'master';

```
import envars from ‘./envars’;
import override from ‘./override’;
export function EnvText() {
    return Object.assign(envars, override);
}
```

envars & override are defined as follows;

```
// envars.js 
export default {
    someText: ‘Standard’,
    aName: ‘Fred’,
};

// override.js (empty object)
export default {
};
```

I need to write a test using vitest (not Jest) that tests that the function works correctly.
I am trying to mock the Object in override.js so that it has the following values;

```
someText: ‘Critical’,
```

I have this so far but its not working.  I'm obviously misunderstanding somewhere but its driving me mad;

```
import { mock, describe, it, vi } from 'vitest';

describe('A Test', () => {
  it('should translate override text & show critical', () => {
    // Mock the override.js file
    vi.mock('override.js', {
      someText: 'Critical',
    });

    // Call the EnvText function
    const result = EnvText('someText');

    // Assertions
    expect(result).toBe('Critical');
  });
});
```

How do I mock this correctly?
Thanks

I tried the above (& many, many variants) such as trying to create a mock object before;

```
const mockOverride {
    someText: ‘Critical’
```

& trying to mock it another way;

```
vi.mock('./overrides.js', () ==> mockOverride);
```

Still no joy.